# Visual Studio online build failure for an empty universal app

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

I just created a new empty universal app (windows 10) and checked it in on my visual studio online project.

The configured build is constantly failing on following error...

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I set build configurations to use VS2015 but without any luck.

I keep thinking there's a simple configuration I'm missing here... but can it also be that it's not yet supported?

The project itself is just the standard template from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inform the solution I found on this thread.

At the time of writing, it appeared that VSTO serves were not yet updated with 
the Windows 10 SDK.

The only way back then to make it run was by creating your own Build VM (through Windows Azure) and link it to your VSTO builds.

I posted the thread and got the answer on the [MSDN TFS forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/edbe5f36-24bd-4b66-a45a-6ff7440e34b2/visual-studio-online-build-failure-for-an-empty-universal-app-on-missing-target-file?forum=TFService).

I have not tried it right now, but since Windows 10 is officially released now, I guess it may work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue running with MSBuild 8.2 target missing under VS2013 Update 5 under Windows 10 TH1. Except my target is Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Cpp.targets.  So not necessarily an issue with Visual Studio but rather the substitution for $(TargetPlatformVersion) in the targets definition:

```
<Import Project="$(TargetPlatformVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Cpp.targets" />
```

I'm building a project from Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb), so I don't think this is your problem (meaning you've not done anything incorrect).

I know this isn't an answer, but I suspect we're caught in a gap in the Windows 10 SDK & Tools.  Those aren't scheduled to be complete and available until 29 July even though VS2015 has RTM'd.  I tried to track down something in the VS2015 release notes without luck.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but, I can see that it wouldn't fit in a comment and that you needed code formatting tags. Others might close-vote, but I'll leave it be :) It seems to contribute useful information to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We now support [building Universal Windows Platform (UWP) projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/apps/universal) on the hosted build service.